# Signing scripts - commit to source control or sign during deployment?

Tags: powershell, code-signing

When creating a PowerShell module (or individual scripts, for that matter), if you must digitally sign them to comply with the defined ExecutionPolicy, should you commit the digitally signed files/scripts to source control?  Or should signing the files/scripts be a step in the deployment process?

Comment: Since your certs eventually expire, it might be worth signing in the deployment process if you can if your cert chain at your organization is automated a la Venafi or similar. I don't think you can technically sign an entire module via any command, as a module's typically a collection of scripts and a manifest (and perhaps media like images etc depending on what you're doing with it, WPF or winforms etc), but you could easily automate signing all of the ps1/psd1/psm1 files in it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Signing should be a step in the deployment process. While signing during development is technically possible, you don't have any benefit from it, but add a bunch of lines of code to every commit.

Comment: Thank you - that's what I was expecting to hear.  I was just looking for some validation. :)